# Use drools as the underlying rule engine for a saas solution offering complex, editable rules

Tags: jboss, drools

I'm in the process of designing a new saas solution that lets users configure relatively complex business rules in a web based environment. I'm leaning towards drools, but the web authoring application that ships with drools is way to complex and 'geeky' to show to the average user.

My idea is to create a simplified web authoring application that connects to drools, but having no experience with drools I have a hard time figuring out if this can be done. So that's my question:

**Can this be done?**

*Secondly*, do you think this is a good approach? (I know the 2nd question is a bit too generic for stackoverflow, but I'd appreciate it if you guys could share some quick pointers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you expect "relatively complex rules" but the existing authoring tool is too complex? The authoring of "complex rules" *is* a *complex* process, and no simple tool will be sufficient. (At least, I haven't seen or heard of one, so far.)

You don't need to "connect to Drools" for an authoring tool. All it has to do is to produce DRL (Drools' native rule language) text which is then compiled.

It *would* be a good approach, but only if you have an answer to the issue of how to create complexity with simple means.

Comment: Ah, that's a fresh approach that seems to fit exactly what I want.
With regards to complex rules and an UI being too complex:
- I will not offer all complexity of drools to the user, so my UI will be simpler to use becasue of that
- A 2nd reason is that I want to integrate the UI of the rule engine (which is only part of a bigger solution with the rest of that solution.
I hope that answers your question.

Comment: I get the general drift. Of course, for a specific (as opposed to generic) solution you should have options for shortcuts.